# Stack trace java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: moa

When I learn the model and evaluate the arff data with this error, I encounter a problem solving.
Thanks

```
Failure reason: -1
*** STACK TRACE **: -1
        at moa.core.DoubleVector.addToValue(DoubleVector.java:64)
        at moa.classifiers.core.attributeclassobservers.NominalAttributeClassObserver.observeAttributeClass(NominalAttributeClassObserver.java:64)
        at moa.classifiers.trees.HoeffdingTree$ActiveLearningNode.learnFromInstance(HoeffdingTree.java:421)
        at moa.classifiers.trees.HoeffdingTree$LearningNodeNBAdaptive.learnFromInstance(HoeffdingTree.java:895)
        at moa.classifiers.trees.HoeffdingTree.trainOnInstanceImpl(HoeffdingTree.java:526)
        at moa.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.trainOnInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:178)
        at moa.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.trainOnInstance(AbstractClassifier.java:249)
        at moa.tasks.LearnModel.doMainTask(LearnModel.java:99)
        at moa.tasks.MainTask.doTaskImpl(MainTask.java:50)
        at moa.tasks.AbstractTask.doTask(AbstractTask.java:57)
        at moa.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:76)
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please visit [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)